# Issues receiving data through bluetooth in my Android application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

For my robotics exam this summer, I am building a robot, that I want to communicate with an Android device via Bluetooth. For this purpose, I am writing my own Android application. I have no issues *sending* data, however i cannot *receive* data. My code for receiving the data, that doesn't work, looks like this:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //Buffer for the incoming message
            int bytes; 
            TextView afstandsTekst = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.afstandsText);
            //Listen to the InputStream
            while(true){
                try {
                    if(mmInStream.available() != 0)
                    try {
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); //Read from the InputStream. This is where the app crashes.
                    }
                    catch(IOException e){
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    break;
                }
                afstandsTekst.setText(String.valueOf(bytes));
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

The app crashes at

```
    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
```

and I do not understand why. I've used the bluetooth page at Android Developers for help (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection), and have tried doing it *exactly* as they did, but that still crashed, which is why I've now tried the code that I have pasted above.
Also, even though the app crashes when run normally, when I choose to debug it in Eclipse on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, the application does not crash, and I do not know why.

This is my first post to this forum, and I very much hope that someone out there will have an answer. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's the code in its entirety:

```
    package skole.migogjesper.hospitalsseng;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.Set;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass.Device;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class HospitalssengActivity extends Activity {
    private String address = "00:06:66:45:B8:DB";
        private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
        protected static final String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = null;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        public ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();                 //Indlæser bluetooth modulet i enheden.
        private BluetoothDevice mmDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        private OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private InputStream mmInStream;
        private char stueDestination = '0';
        private char scannerDestination = '1';
        private char operationsstueDestination = '2';
        private char krematorieDestination = '3';
        private char xrayDestination = '4';
        private char planlagtStueDestination = 'q';
        private char planlagtScannerDestination = 'w';
        private char planlagtOperationsstueDestination = 'e';
        private char planlagtKrematorieDestination = 'r';
        private char planlagtXrayDestination = 't';
        private byte sendByte;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){ //Tjekker om bluetooth er underst¯ttet.
        Toast.makeText(HospitalssengActivity.this, "Enheden understøtter ikke bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){ //Tjekker om bluetooth er tÊndt.
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //Buffer til den indkommende besked
            int bytes; //Bytes der kommer fra read()
            TextView afstandsTekst = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.afstandsText);
            //Lyt efter InputStream indtil der sker en exception
            while(true){
                try {
                    if(mmInStream.available() != 0)
                    try {
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); //Læs fra InputStream
                    }
                    catch(IOException e){
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    break;
                }
                //afstandsTekst.setText(String.valueOf(bytes));
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

public void Connect(BluetoothDevice device){
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null; //Dette er er et midlertidigt objekt, som senere bliver assigned til mmSocket.
    mmDevice = device;

    try { //Få en BluetoothSocket, som kan bruges til at forbinde med en BluetoothDevice
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(HospitalssengActivity.this, "FEJL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mmSocket = tmp;
    try{  //Forbind enheden gennem socket'en. Dette blokerer indtil den er succesfuld eller den fejler.
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        try{mmSocket.close();}  //Fejlet forbindelse. Luk socket'en og hop ud af metoden.
        catch(IOException closeException) {}
        return;
    }
}

public void cancel(){ //Lukker en forbindelse og lukker socket'en.
    try{mmSocket.close();}
    catch(IOException e) {}
}

public void write(byte sendByte){
    try {
        mmOutStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmOutStream.write(sendByte);
        Toast.makeText(HospitalssengActivity.this, "Sendt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
}

public void scanKnap(View view){
    Connect(mmDevice);
}

public void afbrydKnap(View view){
    cancel();
}

public void stueKnap(View view){
    CheckBox planlagtCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.planlagtCheck);
    if(!planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) stueDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
    if(planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) planlagtStueDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
}

public void scannerKnap(View view){
    CheckBox planlagtCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.planlagtCheck);
    if(!planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) scannerDestination;
    write(sendByte);
    }
    if(planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) planlagtScannerDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
}

public void operationsstueKnap(View view){
    CheckBox planlagtCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.planlagtCheck);
    if(!planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) operationsstueDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
    if(planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) planlagtOperationsstueDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
}

public void krematorieKnap(View view){
    CheckBox planlagtCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.planlagtCheck);
    if(!planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) krematorieDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
    if(planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) planlagtKrematorieDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
}

public void xrayKnap(View view){
    CheckBox planlagtCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.planlagtCheck);
    if(!planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) xrayDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
    if(planlagtCheck.isChecked()){
        sendByte = (byte) planlagtXrayDestination;
        write(sendByte);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hey @Ran thanks for the reply! The output of the LogCat window in Eclipse is the following, after the crash:

04-17 16:29:20.559: W/dalvikvm(13854): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a341f8)
04-17 16:29:20.559: E/AndroidRuntime(13854): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1635
04-17 16:29:20.559: E/AndroidRuntime(13854): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 16:29:20.559: E/AndroidRuntime(13854):  at skole.migogjesper.hospitalsseng.HospitalssengActivity$1.run(HospitalssengActivity.java:71)
04-17 16:29:20.559: E/AndroidRuntime(13854):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 0):

If it runs in the debugger and not normally that sounds like a race condition. The only variable that seems to be available in more than one thread is mmInStream.  What are you doing to mmInStream outside of this thread?

A race condition is when two threads can both access shared mutable state (in this case mmInStream).  Sometimes one thread wins and you see one result and the other time another thread wins and you see another result.  These things can be very difficult to debug.

Can you post the code around where you create the thread?

Looking at the code you posted I don't see where mmInstream is initialized.  That would cause a null pointer exception like you reported, but it would also happen in the debugger (unless that thread never ran).

Comment: What exactly is a race condition @JonStrayer? I'm fairly new to programming, and wish to learn :-) And actually, I'm not doing anything with mmInStream outside of this thread, well, except for creating it with: private InputStream mmInStream;

Comment: Okay, I'll try posting the code in it's entirety @JonStrayer.

Answer (score 0):

## You should not use threads.

Use Service for background stuff, and for threads use ASyncTask instead of Thread!

As a hint: You can broadcast **locally** between the Service and the activity! (You have to import android support library for that(see LocalBroadcast).

Android already means OS on top of another OS(Linux). You do not need to handle thread communication yourself, let Android take care of that!

Comment: As I've said in one of my previous comments I'm not a very experienced programmer, and definately not with Android (this is my first "real" Android application), so I am basically just going along with Google's documentation and some of my previous experience. How would I go about creating something that continually listens to incoming bluetooth communication with the methods you suggested @Radu ?

Comment: It's hard to explain all of it, but you need to have a Service (which always runs on background - you can start reading on it). Then, in the service, monitor the state of your Bluetooth Connection. If disconnected, start the ASyncTask that listens for connections and the one that tries to make a new connection. If connected, start the ASyncTask that reads incoming data and writes outgoing data. Communication between all of these can be done a lot of ways. I do it with LocalBroadcast. Again, read the Android docs for all these classes.

Comment: Hmm okay, I might try to look into it, but it sounds like it requires almost a complete rewrite of the aplication, something that I unfortunately do not have time for. Still, thanks for the answer @Radu!

Comment: It may look bad, but it should not take you more than a week (40 hrs). It is incredibly simple to program in Android. For example I changed my app from a single activity with about 7 views to 2 activities, each in its own module, etc in about 2 hours. And I'm a noob too.

Comment: Our issue is that we only have 'till friday noon to finnish both the robot itself and the programming, so I simply do not think that we have the time. Still, I'll try to remember it untill the next time I'll need it. Again, thanks @Radu